How can I extract the solana sent amount in the instructions of a versionedtansaction in rust?
Using rust I have a versionedTransaction, I am able to check if it interfaces with raydium by running a check on the account_keys:
fn is_raydium(tx: &VersionedTransaction) -> bool {
    let raydium_program_ids: Vec<Pubkey> = RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_IDS
        .iter()
        .map(|id| Pubkey::from_str(id).unwrap())
        .collect();

    match &tx.message {
        VersionedMessage::V0(message) | VersionedMessage::Legacy(message) => {
            for instruction in &message.instructions {
                if instruction.program_id_index as usize >= message.account_keys.len() {
                    continue;
                }
                let program_id = &message.account_keys[instruction.program_id_index as usize];
                if raydium_program_ids.contains(program_id) {
                    info!("Found Raydium Program ID in instruction: {:?}", instruction);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    false
}

So I know that my transaction I'm interested in is involved in a raydium transaction.
However - now I want to see if the transaction involved sending solana to raydium, and how much.
How do I achieve this programmatically and purely from getting it from VersionedTransaction without resorting to the RPC call?

If anyone comes looking... the answer was to do a simulation on the transaction and read the before and after tokens and figure out direction by which transaction changed value on which side. Jito-ts has the simulateBalance capability which returns both instead of jist the simulate from vanilla solana
